# How do get query string parameter in sveltekit?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

I'm trying to the `/login?ref=/some/path` parameter to redirect to after login:

```js
const ref = $page.url.searchParams.get('ref') || '/dashboard';
```

However I get this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'searchParams')`

Comment: I tested you code, and works perfect. Which version of SveteKit are you running?

Comment: 3.x is what I have

Comment: That is the svelte version, what is your SvelteKit version? Update to the latest verserion (1.0.0-next.294)

Comment: "@sveltejs/kit": "1.0.0-next.294",

Comment: For reference: sveltekit example: https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/page-store

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The above solutions won't work. This is the new way:

```js
export async function load({ params, url }) {
    let lang = url.searchParams.get('lang');
    let q = url.searchParams.get('q');
    return { lang, q };
}
```

Then, please reach it as this:

```js
import { page } from '$app/stores';
$page.data.q
```

Thanks to Richard this is much better than acknowledging `export var lang` in each page

Comment: Why do you destructure params? You are not using it. Plus, `$page.data` is used in a page **that need to access data from a child page or layout**:  https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#using-url-data https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#$page-data

Comment: Actually, we are using it. That's why included. Good that it's reachable from server side

Comment: @Big_Boulard you can also do it like this `$page.url.searchParams.get("q")` now with latest sveltekit without need `load({ params, url })`

Comment: @Bitdom8 your are _not_ using `params` in your function, only `url`.

Answer (score 27):

You can get the query string parameters from the `url` property of the object passed to the `load` function of a page:

```js
<script context="module">
  export function load({ url }) {
    const ref = url.searchParams.get('ref') || '/dashboard';
    return {
      props: {
        ref
      }
    };
  }
</script>
<script>
  export let ref;

  // do stuff
</script>
```

More info on the `load` function, its input format and its reactivity [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/loading#input) (SvelteKit docs).

Comment: Is there a way to get it from `$page`?

Comment: Yes you can, in similar fashion, see the code in the `Header` component in [this Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-rmgmwd?file=src%2Flib%2Fheader%2FHeader.svelte&terminal=dev) I quickly put together. Which, incidentally, is the way you're attempting to do it in your own code, so you might want to check that your SvelteKit version is up-to-date.

Comment: Yeah that’s what I thought. I have svelte 3.x

Comment: It's the SvelteKit version that matters here. Kit is where the routing, etc. is handled.

Comment: `    "@sveltejs/kit": "next",`

Answer (score 23):

You can use the following example:

```js
import { page } from '$app/stores'

$page.url.searchParams.get('ref')
```